# How to connect with different node if main node get down in private ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain, jquery

I have created private ethreum blockchain,It is hosted in LAN network and connected with 3 nodes,
i am using one main Node IP (e.g 192.168.1.27:8546) to connect my application(created using web3.js truffle) with blockchain
 but if that main Node is get down then how to connect with Other node using application??

Comment: simply, get the ip address of another node as you got the ip of main node. then you can interact with that chain.

Comment: yes, but it is not possible to check which Node is working and change IP accordingly every-time in application's config

Comment: use if else case for, if connected is true for one ip then use it otherwise go to next ip address. it works fine unless down all nodes.